# wpf,How to find mainControl?

Tags: wpf

How to find UserControl Layer by grid?

```
<UserControl
 ... ...
 >
  <Grid name="grid">
  </Grid>
```

I want to add resource to UserControl Layer in CodeBehind.

Grid contain lots of TextBox.
it is invalid when i add resource to Grid.

```
ResourceDictionary resource = new ResourceDictionary();
            Style style = new Style(typeof(TextBox));
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBox.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(0)));
```

Comment: In what context are you trying to find UserControl?

Comment: Please add some details of what you are tying to do

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) to navigate and search in the visual tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a reference to UserControl in code behind, you can use `this` keyword.

If you want to refer to it in a binding, use Ancestor binding like following :

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=PropertyName}
```